# Non-volatile way to use table for data validation without using INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

One place where I often use the INDIRECT function is for data validation. If I have a table called `tabColor` with a column called `Color`, and I want to use that for **data validation**, you would think you could set up the data validation as a list with this formula:

```
=tabColor[Color]
```

However, this causes an error. If you wrap the formula with `INDIRECT`, it works:

```
=INDIRECT("tabColor[Color]")
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Will using `INDIRECT` in data validation cause the cell to be marked as volatile?
2. Is there a non-volatile way to use a table for data validation?

Btw, if you want to know more about volatile functions, a nice write-up can be found at
[chandoo.org](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. The data validation list is refreshed whenever any calculation cycle in the workbook runs. This is a form of invisible parasitic calculation lag when volatile formulas are used in Data Validation, Named Ranges, Conditional Formatting rules, etc.
2. Create a *Named Range* with the *Refers to:* as `=tabColor[color]` then use the name of the named range as the Data Validation list's *Source:*. Sadly, table naming conventions have not caught up with all of the features where they should be able to be used directly.